# CSS doesn't load in facebook embeded browser on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, facebook

I have a problem with facebook embeded browser (iPhone only). 
Random users report that some of the pages on the website are not loading well in facebook embeded  browser.

Problem appears randomly. Random users, random pages. Page loads, but it does not load or apply CSS. There are  no console errors on regular chrome browser.

At first, I had one report, so I thought it's some cache issue on the client, but I got another report recently.

We tested this on 50 users, with various devices. 2 of them had problems, but on different pages. Android users never reported any issues.

I would post some code, but I do not know what to post, since problem appears randomly, and in rare occasions. I never experienced it myself.
I also tried to look for similar reports, but I could not find any.

Someone had a similar experience or problem with fb embeded browser?

Comment: Could you share your website URL so I can check here in my iPhone?

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: getting same problem, anyone found a solution

Comment: @suneth check my new answer

Comment: Something similar happens to me on Android devices, in my case it does not recognize some properties such as row-gap, so I chose to use margin, it must be because the facebook mobile browser is not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was media attribute for css link tag. Had to set it to all.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: did you removed media attribute or used specifi8c attribute for fix this

Comment: i had to set it's value to "all"

Answer (score 1):

run your app in debug mode through Xcode to see what is causing the web-view connection flickering. the problem you mention may due to network shifting from wifi - mobile or reverse.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem at all. Works fine on most of the devices. I had maybe 2-3 reports about this. All from iPhone 6 and 7. Problem continues even after user refreshes page several time, no matter which network. Wifi or 4g.

Answer (score 1):

That is a tough one! I think it is most likely a problem with facebook's browser as opposed to your website. Maybe wait to see when facebook next update their app and test again (I believe they usually update their app every 2 weeks). Sometimes it can be a mix of browser problems and dodgy internet connections.

Edit:

If you could add more detail as to what the problems are or even what website it is, I could have a look for any potential hiccups?